# for a given group name, print all the users and the groups they are in including the given one, using only loops, cat, grep, and no awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following Bash script, for a given group name, print all the users and the groups they are in including the given one:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Get group name
groupName=$1

## Groups file data saved into groups variable
groups=$(cat /etc/group)

for user in $(awk -F ':' "/${groupName}/"'{print $4}' /etc/group | tr ',' '\n'); do
    echo $user "- grupuri:" "$(groups | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' ';');"
done

## awk -F ':' '/certuser/ { print $4 }' /etc/group
## Gets each users in the $group ('certuser') group, seperated by a ,
## Using awk to remove group info so we're only keeping users


## | tr ',' '\n'
## Pipes that csv to the for-loop

## echo $user "- grupuri:" "$(groups | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' ';');"
## Use the groups command to get all users in that group
## then it replaces all spaces with ';'
```

It is working good, but I was trying to get it to work without using the awk (I am not allowed to) and instead only use for loops, grep, cat.. as in the following:
#!/bin/bash

```
## Get group name
groupName=$1
str="${groupName}"
echo $str

for user in $(cat /etc/passwd  | cut -d: -f1); do
    echo -n $user "- grupuri:"
    grep $user /etc/group | cut -d: -f1 | grep $str
    echo
done
```

but of course the above would not work. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

Output of the current script (the first one shown above) (desired output, but using the forbidden commands):

```
  root - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  daemon - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  clark - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  cups - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  clark - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  bin - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  clark - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  polkitd - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  clark - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  clark - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  daemon - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  bin - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
  mongodb - grupuri: sys;network;power;lp;wheel;clark;
```

Content of /etc/passwd

```
  postgres:x:969:969:PostgreSQL user:/var/lib/postgres:/bin/bash
  mongodb:x:968:968::/var/lib/mongodb:/usr/bin/nologin
  dhcpcd:x:967:967:dhcpcd privilege separation:/var/lib/dhcpcd:/usr/bin/nologin
  openvpn:x:965:965:OpenVPN:/:/usr/bin/nologin
  mysql:x:964:964:MariaDB:/var/lib/mysql:/usr/bin/nologin
```

content of /etc/group

```
  lp:x:991:cups,clark
  optical:x:990:
  render:x:989:
  storage:x:988:
  uucp:x:987:
  video:x:986:
  users:x:985:
  sys:x:3:bin,clark
```

Comment: Can you clarify what does not work in the alternative script ?

Comment: `cut` does not seem to be allowed either, does it?

Comment: please update the question with **a)** sample from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, **b)** the (wrong) output generated by your script (when run against the sample input files) and **c)** the (correct) desired output (when run against the sample input files)

Comment: **but of course the above would not work** Why?  What happens?  See @markp-fuso's comment.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. I will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do         # Loop on the users in /etc/passwd
   grpdat=$(groups $user)                          # Read the output of groups into grpdat
   grpdat1=$(cut -d: -f2 <<< "$grpdat")            # Extract the groups only without the user and read into grpdat1
   if grep -q "$1" <<<"$grpdat1"                   # If grpdat1 contains the group passed as a parameter then print grpdat1
   then
      echo $grpdat
   fi
done
```